# Macro failing to get correct PivotTable name

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, pivot-table

I have the following code (thanks to an answer on this site) that selects a sheet in Excel, and picks out the name of a pivot table on it.

```
Sub PivotTableName()

    Sheets("PivotTable").Select

    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Set pt = ActivePivotTable

    If pt Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No Active pivot table"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Active = " & pt.Name

    End If

End Sub

Function ActivePivotTable() As PivotTable
    Dim pt As PivotTable, rv
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        Debug.Print pt.Name, pt.TableRange2.Address
        If Not pt.Name = "" Then
            Set ActivePivotTable = pt
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next pt
End Function
```

The pivot table is imported from a MySQL database, and is the only pivot table on the sheet. If the excel spreadsheet is opened and the table is imported (Using MySQL for Excel add-in) and then the macro is run, the macro works perfectly, giving the answer

```
Active = project1.mytable
```

However, if this pivot table is deleted, and imported again, Excel changes the newly imported pivot table name to "project1.mytable.2", however, when I run the macro, it still returns

```
Active = project1.mytable
```

I delete the pivot table using ctrl+a and then Delete, when I have a cell in the pivot table selected.

Does anyone know why it isn't picking up the correct name?

Comment: If it's the only one on the sheet, why not just use `Sheets("PivotTable").PivotTables(1).Name`?

Comment: @Jay not sure what is the purpose of your code. What do you need to do with the `Name` of the Pivot-Table ? Does your sheet always contains a single `PivotTable` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 `PivotTable` in "PivotTable" sheet, the code below is sufficient:

```
Sub PivotTableName()

Dim i As Long

With Sheets("PivotTable")

    If .PivotTables.Count > 0 Then

        ' ==== DEBUG SCRIPT ====
        For i = 1 To .PivotTables.Count
            Debug.Print "Active = " & .PivotTables(1).Name
        Next i

        Debug.Print "Active = " & .PivotTables(1).Name
    Else
        Debug.Print "No Active pivot table"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this is still returning "Active = project1.mytable" instead of  "Active = project1.mytable.2". On Excel, the Table Name under the Pivot Table tools is "project1.mytable.2"

Comment: @Jay are you sure you deleted the previous pivot-table ?

Comment: @Jay try the edited code, added some Debug script, tell me what you get

Comment: I used Ctrl+a and then hit Delete, it appeared to delete the entire table, is there a better way to remove a PivotTable? I ran the code here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2248-excel-list-all-pivot-tables-in-workbook.html and it tells me I just have one PivotTable in the entire workbook (as expected), however it also has the incorrect name for the pivot table

Comment: I just ran the updated code. It returned "Active = project1.mytable\r\n
Active = project1.mytable"